# Flask-Testing signals not supported error

Tags: python, flask, flask-testing

When running my tests I am getting the following traceback.

```
in get_context_variable
raise RuntimeError("Signals not supported")
RuntimeError: Signals not supported
```

**__init__.py**

```
from flask_testing import TestCase

from app import create_app, db


class BaseTest(TestCase):
    BASE_URL = 'http://localhost:5000/'

    def create_app(self):
        return create_app('testing')

    def setUp(self):
        db.create_all()

    def tearDown(self):
        db.session.remove()
        db.drop_all()

    def test_setup(self):
        response = self.client.get(self.BASE_URL)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

**test_routes.py**

```
from . import BaseTest


class TestMain(BaseTest):

    def test_empty_index(self):
        r = self.client.get('/')
        self.assert200(r)
        self.assertEqual(self.get_context_variable('partners'), None)
```

It appears that the `get_context_variable` function call is where the error is coming from. I also receive this error if I try and use `assert_template_used`. Having a rather difficult time finding any resolution to this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Flask only provides signals as an optional dependency.  Flask-Testing requires signals in some places and raises an error if you try to do something without them.  For some reason, some messages are more vague than others Flask-Testing raises elsewhere.  <sub>(This is a good place for a beginner to contribute a pull request.)</sub>

You need to install the [blinker](https://pythonhosted.org/blinker/) library to enable [signal support](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/signals/) in Flask.

```
$ pip install blinker
```